# Page Not Rendering After MySQL INSERT With Form

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to get my admin dashboard page to render after the add user form is successfully submitted. The following code is executing when a user is being inserted:

```
app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res,next){
  var context = {};
  pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`,`timestamp`,`company`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password, req.query.company], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    res.render('adminDash',context);
  });
});
```

The record is being inserted into the table successfully, but the page stays on the populated form and does not render `adminDash`. The `adminDash` handlebars contains the following:

```
<h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>

<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/add-user">Add a User</a></p>
<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/edit-delete-user">Edit/Delete a User</a></p>
<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/add-admin-user">Add Admin User</a></p>
<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/edit-delete-admin-user">Edit/Delete Admin User</a></p>
<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/admin-login">Generate Report</a></p>
```

The `addUser` form contains the following:

```
<form id="userForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add User</legend>
            <p>First Name: <input id="fname" type="text" name="fname"/></p>
            <p>Last Name: <input  id="lname" type="text" name="lname"/></p>
            <p>Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/></p>
            <p>Company: <input id="company" type="text" name="company"/></p>
            <p>Password: <input id="password" type="text" name="password"/></p>
            <button type="button">Attach Signature</button>
        </fieldset>
        <input id="addUser" type="submit" name="add" value="Add User" onclick="addRow()" />


</form>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Do I have the render in the wrong spot? Is there something wrong with the page it is trying to render? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use hardcored `18.219.103.143:3000` within your links if you change host/ip you can change all these links again.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Right. I will change to a constant for scalability. I don't think that is causing my issue, however.

Comment: " I don't think that is causing my issue, however." indeed

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this

```
models.User.create(function({
         //Your Query goes here
})
.then(function(result){
  res.render('',{
   result:result

});

}).catch(function(err){
 console.log(err);
})

and in your ADmin Dashboard try to call this Result in a forEach loop

<% result.forEach(results) %>
```

Comment: this whole portion? `pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`,`timestamp`,`company`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password, req.query.company], 
  function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log("Company does not exist");
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    res.render('adminDash',context);
  });`

Comment: No only your Query till req.query.company

Comment: My insert function is now this but I get a syntax error `app.get('/insert-user',function(req,res,next){
  var context = {};

  models.User.create(function({
         pool.query("INSERT INTO user (`fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`,`timestamp`,`company`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)", 
  [req.query.fname, req.query.lname, req.query.email, req.query.password, req.query.company],
})
.then(function(result){
  res.render('',{
   result:result

});

}).catch(function(err){
 console.log(err);
})
});
);
});`

Comment: try editing this according to your Question no need to Put a query now this is a Sequelize method of Query

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Apologies. But I'm just confused where all of the above code fits into my existing structure.

Comment: in your add-user function my code structure goes there

Answer (score 0):

```
{
                models.Page.findOne({
                    where :{slug:slug}
                    })
                            models.Page.create({
                                title: title,
                                slug: slug,
                                content: content,
                                sorting: 0
                            })

                                .then((page)=>{

                                req.flash('success', 'Page added!');
                                res.redirect('/admin/pages');
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                            })
                        }
                    });
```